# Распознавание Лица на Python

Tags: python, opencv, web-camera

пишу программу которая бы распознавала лицо через веб-камеру. Принципе код есть, но есть 2 строки которые тормозят поток с видео камеры. Что можно с ними сделать?

```
locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image, model=MODEL)
encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, locations)
```

Comment: можно делать это не каждый кадр, а раз в 5 кадров. Если поток идет с скоростью 25 кадров, то для пользователя в большинстве случаев побоку - каждый кадр или 5 раз в секунду.

Comment: тоже думал думал об этом, но не мог найти описание.